# Problem trying to retrieve info from a json file with an api with php

Tags: php, json

first, thanks in advance for your help.

I have some problems trying to get data from an online JSON file. I using PHP (with cURL). I can access the file and I can put an echo and see all of the "raw" data in it. I want to find a way to show only the type of data I want (for example, only a movie). I use the foreach but I got a notice and a warning.

I tried with the second argument of json_decode and try with foreach but it doesn't work. I did some research but even if I try, there is always the same errors. I tried with "movie" from the beginning of the file but I also have the same error. Is it because "movie" doesn't have a "[" (it is also twice)? Then, I tried with the "apiver" but same error.

```php
//getting the access of the file - cURL is working fine
$sJSON = see_json('link');
$aJSON = json_decode($sJSON, true);

foreach($aJSON->apiver as $mydatas) {
  foreach ($mydatas->values as $value) {
    echo $value->value . "<br>";
  }
}
```

```
//beginning of the JSON file
"movie": {
        "1010414": {
            "title_fr": "Godzilla II - Roi des Monstres",
            "lang_ov": "en",
            "release_de_ch": "2019-05-30",
            "title": "Godzilla: King of the Monsters",
            "release_fr_ch": "2019-05-29",
            "title_de": "Godzilla II: King of the Monsters",
            "id": "1010414"
        },
        "1011095": {
            "title_fr": "Le Parc des merveilles",
            "lang_ov": "en",
            "release_de_ch": "2019-04-11",
            "title": "Wonder Park",
            "release_fr_ch": "2019-04-03",
            "title_de": "Willkommen im Wunder Park",
            "id": "1011095"

//far in the file
"apiver": 210,
    "sched": [
        {
            "ts": 1559201400,
            "id": "VS1258",
            "duration": 129,
            "movie": "1012351",
            "site": "SPE",
            "aud": 3,
            "age": "6/10",
            "lang": "de"
        },
        {
            "ts": 1559202300,
            "id": "VM33930",
            "duration": 85,
            "movie": "1012655",
            "site": "MOS",
            "aud": 3,
            "age": "6/6",
            "lang": "de"
```

I want to show all data from "apiver" but it results in 2 errors :

> Notice: Trying to get property 'apiver' of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Cinema Pathe\curl.php on line 28
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Cinema Pathe\curl.php on line 28

What am I doing wrong?

Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: First of all, you want to go read up on what the second parameter of json_decode does.

Comment: To add on to what @04FS points to, you can use 'gettype()' on '$aJSON' to see if you're using the variable correctly. :)

Comment: Also don't `movie` needs to be array of objects like `sched` in your example?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I can suggest you to use the `file_get_contents` builtin function for fetching the content from the API.

```
$sJSON = file_get_contents("link");
```

Now come to the decode of JSON file, the `json_decode` is good. But I suggest you not to use the `true` as 2nd Argument, as it converts the Object into Associative array.

```
$response = json_decode($sJSON);
```

Now use the `$response->movie` to see the movie objects.
Now to iter in the object, use `foreach` loop and use the `$value` variable

```
foreach ($response->movie as $key => $value) {
    // Do something
}
```

Now, to get the individual objects use `$value->title_fr` and so on inside the `foreach` loop.

I'm giving an example to show the movie names in a new line

```
$sJSON = file_get_contents("link");
$response = json_decode($sJSON);

foreach ($response->movie as $key => $value) {
    echo $value->title_fr;
    echo "<br>";    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can change to `$aJSON['apiver']` in you `foreach()` loop or change this line `$aJSON = json_decode($sJSON, true);` to `$aJSON = json_decode($sJSON);`